# iOS 5.1 App running with xcode 4.6.2 with target iOS 5.1, not able to restrict some views from orientation?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode4

I developed an app with Xcode 4.4 and iOS 5.1. I updated Xcode to 4.6.2 and iOS is 6.1, but I have selected the target as iOS 5.1 (even though I am using Xcode 4.6.2). My app supports all orientations.

My question is: I want to restrict some views in landscape mode, it is working fine in the simulator but when I am running the app in iPhone 5 device, my methods are not working, kindly help me?

Comment: check the OS version in the device.

Comment: i have seen my iphone os also, it is 6.1.4

Comment: What methods are you using to restrict the orientation?

Comment: - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}


I am using the above method, am i wrong?

Comment: can any one help me please

Answer (score 1):

In your view controller(s) where you want to restrict your orientation I would do the following:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape;
}
```

Regarding your iPhone 5 the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` was deprecated with iOS6 so you're going to have to do an OS check and implement/override the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my app and it works perfect!

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

When you want a view only for portrait use this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: this is working fine in simulator, when iam running the same thing on iphone5 , it's not working.

Comment: Delete the app from your phone and re build it on your phone.